# Rails Routes: Need regex for permalink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a following routes in my `routes.rb`

```
constraints(category: REGEX_PERMALINK, course: REGEX_PERMALINK, lecture: REGEX_PERMALINK) do
  get '/:category', to: 'notes#index'
  get '/:category/:course', to: 'notes#index'
  get '/:category/:course/:lecture', to: 'notes#index'
end
```

The `REGEX_PERMALINK` is `/\d.+/`. When I go to `localhost:3001/admin`, `:category` is set to `admin`. It's wrong and I'm not going to admin. `:category`, `:course`, `:lecture` are only start with `id` then slug /permalink/. For example: `localhost:3001/1-foo/2-bar/3-me` should `category: 1-foo`, `course: 2-bar`, `lecture: 3-me`. Can you guys write a regex for `REGEX_PERMALINK`.

Thank you for help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following RegEx

^\d-\w+

This means, expression starting with digit followed by dash and \w will match to any word character (letter, number, underscore). And + means one or more time.

Comment: Thank you reply but it's not work. Result is the same :(

Comment: I'm getting following errors:
`verify_regexp_requirement': Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements: /^\d-\w+/ (ArgumentError)`

Here is the what I type: `REGEX_PERMALINK = /^\d-\w+/`

Comment: You're right. It's working here is the [test url](http://rubular.com/r/ke2EIwb3yJ). When I set `REGEX_PERMALINK = /^\d-\w+/`. It shows me above error.

Comment: You are getting this error because anchor (^) character is not allowed in routing. If anchor is removed then expression can be started with character also which should not happen? Right?

Comment: `ANCHOR_CHARACTERS_REGEX = %r{\A(\\A|\^)|(\\Z|\\z|\$)\Z}` here's the regex for checking route. Getting this from [Rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L137)

Comment: \A\d-\w+ Please try this and let me know.

Comment: Getting same errors. I'm going to ask Rails core developers, why they are avoid ^ or \A. Thank you for helping me :D